# Ciclo de vida de fragments - Error

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

Buen dia
Mi aplicacion consta de un activity donde se carga inicialmente un Fragment (F)

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.content_frame, newFragment).commit();
```

F contiene 3 botones, cada uno de esos botones redirige a otro fragment (F1,F2,F3). A su vez, F2 contiene un RecyclerView que redirige a otro fragment (F2a) con ciertos datos.

```
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```

F2a pasa varias veces por su OnCreateView a pesar de estar visualizando otro fragment. hasta que llega un momento donde se rompe por no poder bindear sus elementos. que podra ser?

Por si sirve de algo aclaro que hago uso de un boton atras ubicado en el Activity

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

y que para bindear los elementos uso ButterKnife

Comment: te recomiendo brindar mayores detalles, mostrar si es posible el error que presentas, saludos.

Comment: Y el LogCat que error muestra?